# Run Jmeter from Jenkins with Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, jmeter

I have Jenkins with the performance plugin successfully installed in Docker. Now i would like to run jmeter from Jenkins. What is the best way to do that ? I running jmeter on a AWS server. Is there a plugin for that ?

Comment: Use either the gradle plugin or maven plugin for jmeter, to launch jmeter and run a test. Disclaimer: I am the author of this [gradle plugin](http://jmeter.foragerr.net/)